# A QGraphicsPixmapItem with a transparency gradient

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I would like to apply a transparency gradient on a QGraphicsPixmapItem but I don't know how to go about it, for now I can only apply the transparency on the whole QGraphicsPixmapItem (not the gradient). The item undergoes a mirror effect (like an element on a wall which is reflected on the ground), then I would like to set up this gradient of transparency (from top to bottom; quite opaque at the top ... and in several stages of transparencies, it ends up being completely transparent at the bottom of the item), then I add blur. This is the part of the transparency gradient that I can't seem to do... I don't understand how it can work. Everything I've tried doesn't work. Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Here is a fairly short code:

```
for item in self.scene.selectedItems() :
    # Width
    item_height = item.boundingRect().height()
    # mirroir
    item.setTransform(QTransform(1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
    # 
    item.setOpacity(0.7)
    # Blur
    blur = QGraphicsBlurEffect()
    blur.setBlurRadius(8)
    item.setGraphicsEffect(blur)
    item.setPos(100, 100 + 2 * (int(item_height)))
    ##############################################
    """
    alphaGradient = QLinearGradient(item.boundingRect().topLeft(), item.boundingRect().bottomLeft())
    alphaGradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt.transparent)
    alphaGradient.setColorAt(0.5, Qt.black)
    alphaGradient.setColorAt(1.0, Qt.transparent)
    effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
    effect.setOpacityMask(alphaGradient)
    item.setGraphicsEffect(effect) ########
    """
    ##############################################
    """
    opacity = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
    lg = QLinearGradient()
    lg.setStart(0, 0)
    lg.setFinalStop(0, 100)
    lg.setColorAt(0, Qt.transparent)
    lg.setColorAt(0.5, Qt.transparent)
    lg.setColorAt(1.0, Qt.transparent)
    opacity.setOpacityMask(lg)
    #opacity.setOpacity(1)
    item.setGraphicsEffect(opacity)
    """
    ##############################################
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one single QGraphicsEffect can be applied for each target item (or widget), so you have two options:

- create a *new* image that applies the opacity gradient (using QPainter composition modes) and only set the blur effect;
- set the opacity effect on a parent item;

In both cases, I'd suggest you to create the "mirror" item as a *child* of the actual QGraphicsPixmapItem, which will ensure that it will always follow what happens to the parent, including visibility and geometry changes, transformations, etc.

### Generate the mirror image with a transparency gradient

For this, we use the [composition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#composition-modes) features of QPainter, and specifically the `CompositionMode_SourceIn` which allows to use a gradient as source for the alpha channel of the image that is being drawn.

The procedure is the following:

1. create a new image based on the size of the mirrored one;
2. create a gradient that has full opacity at 0 and is transparent at 1 (or less);
3. draw that gradient on the image;
4. set the composition mode;
5. draw the mirrored image;
6. create a QGraphicsPixmapItem based on that image;

```
class MirrorPixmapItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mirror = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self)
        self.blurEffect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=8)
        self.mirror.setGraphicsEffect(self.blurEffect)
        if not self.pixmap().isNull():
            self.createMirror()

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        old = self.pixmap()
        super().setPixmap(pixmap)
        if old == pixmap:
            return
        self.createMirror()

    def setOffset(self, *args):
        super().setOffset(*args)
        if not self.mirror.pixmap().isNull():
            self.mirror.setOffset(self.offset())

    def createMirror(self):
        source = self.pixmap()
        if source.isNull():
            self.mirror.setPixmap(source)
            return

        scale = .5
        height = int(source.height() * scale)

        output = QtGui.QPixmap(source.width(), height)
        output.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        qp = QtGui.QPainter(output)
        grad = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height)
        grad.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.black)
        grad.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        qp.fillRect(output.rect(), grad)
        qp.setCompositionMode(qp.CompositionMode_SourceIn)
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, 
            source.transformed(QtGui.QTransform().scale(1, -scale)))
        qp.end()

        self.mirror.setPixmap(output)
        self.mirror.setY(self.boundingRect().bottom())
        self.mirror.setOffset(self.offset())
```

### Set the opacity on the parent item

In this case, we still have the blur effect on the mirror item, but we apply a QGraphicsOpacityEffect on the parent (the original image) and use the [`opacityMask`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html#opacityMask-prop) that includes *both* the original image and the mirror, will be at full opacity down to the height of the original, and then begins to fade out to full transparency for the mirror.

```
class MirrorPixmapItem2(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.opacity = QtWidgets.QGraphicsOpacityEffect(opacity=1)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.opacity)
        self.mirror = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(self)
        self.blurEffect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=8)
        self.mirror.setGraphicsEffect(self.blurEffect)
        if not self.pixmap().isNull():
            self.createMirror()

    # ... override setPixmap() and setOffset() as above

    def createMirror(self):
        source = self.pixmap()
        if source.isNull():
            self.mirror.setPixmap(source)
            return

        scale = .5

        self.mirror.setPixmap(
            source.transformed(QtGui.QTransform().scale(1, -scale)))
        self.mirror.setPos(self.boundingRect().bottomLeft())
        self.mirror.setOffset(self.offset())

        height = source.height()
        gradHeight = height + height * scale

        grad = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, gradHeight)
        grad.setColorAt(height / gradHeight, QtCore.Qt.black)
        grad.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        self.opacity.setOpacityMask(grad)
```

---

This is the result, as you can see there's no visible difference, which approach to use is a matter of choice, but the first one might be slightly better from the perspective of performance, as no additional effect is required when the items are drawn, which might be important if you are going to have many (as in hundreds or thousands) image items and/or at high resolutions.

[image: Result of the effects]

Comment: Wow, that's help! Thank you musicamante. I will look your suggestions, even if I don't understand everything. For the moment I don't see how to call and set up one of your two classes for the selected item.

Comment: @ekdmekdm as explained in the question, I suggest you to create *unique* items that represent the pixmap *and* its mirrored image. If you just want to show the mirrored image under certain conditions, then just `hide()` the mirror item, and show it when you need it.